# How to output ANSI Escape Sequences with XSLT / xsltproc

Tags: xml, bash, xslt

I'd like to transform an XML file (e.g. a junit.xml file) with xsltproc (so XSLT 1.1!) to produce a text file that will be displayed in a unix-like terminal. For clarity, I'd like to highlight some sections with colors using ANSI Escape Sequence.

For instance, given the example XML file `in.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<red>I love XML</red>
```

and an example XSLT file `color.xsl`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="red">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using `xsltproc`, I obtain:

[image]

How can I change the XSLT file to produce the result below?

[image]

I tried:

- using `select="concat(string('&#27;[31m'),.)"`. I get `parser error : xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 27`.
- using `CDATA` etc
- or `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">`

But this simple thing seems just impossible with `xsltproc`.

---

**Note**: For now, I'll just add a post-processing step, like using `select="concat(string('&amp;#27;[31m'),.)"/>` in XSL file and then

```
xsltproc color.xsl in.xml | sed -r 's/&#27;/\x1b/g'
```

Comment: Does xsltproc have a switch to support XML 1.1 instead of XML 1.0? Because in XML 1.1 you can use `&#27;`.

Comment: I suspect you'll find that xsltproc is only capable of producing output containing valid XML 1.0 characters, which excludes control characters such as x1B.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to bump XML version. Unfortunately it is indeed not supported by xsltproc.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you can author the XSLT as XML 1.1, for instance with Saxon 9 or 10

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:param name="color-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
        select="map { 'red' : '31m',
        'blue' : '34m',
        'black' : '30m',
        'green' : '32m',
        'yellow' : '33m',
        'magenta' : '35m',
        'cyan' : '36m'
        }"/>
    
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="red | blue | black | green | yellow | magenta | cyan">&#27;[{$color-map(local-name())}{.}&#27;[39;49m</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or with Xalan C++:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl" version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="color-map">
        <color name="green">32m</color>
        <color name="cyan">36m</color>
        <color name="magenta">35m</color>
        <color name="red">31m</color>
        <color name="yellow">33m</color>
        <color name="blue">34m</color>
        <color name="black">30m</color>
    </xsl:param>
    
    <xsl:variable name="colors" select="exsl:node-set($color-map)/color"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="red | blue | black | green | yellow | magenta | cyan">
        <xsl:text>&#27;[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$colors[@name = local-name(current())]"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#27;[39;49m</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It appears that xsltproc doesn't support XML 1.1, when I run the above XSLT 1.0 but XML 1.1 stylesheet that works fine with Xalan C++ with xsltproc I get a warning "parser warning : Unsupported version '1.1'".

Comment: fwiw - to get this to work with _xsltproc_ I used this variant [template.xsl](https://paste.ee/p/3N7t3). Then via the CLI run: `echo -e "$(xsltproc /some/path/to/template.xsl /some/path/to/in.xml)"`

Comment: Thanks for the interesting stylesheets, although they indeed don't work for xsltproc. One more reason to switch to better tools, but not an easy option for us. If there is no better answer, I'll rephrase my question and accept yours. @RobC, thanks for the interesting workaround! You basically output escaped escape sequence, that you let echo to process. A bit of a hack compared to sed post-proc, but very clever.